# Commit merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I want to push files to git even when there is a merge conflict (in this case I want to push the conflict). I don´t find the way. Git doesn't allow me to commit due to the conflict, but I want to push this conflict.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git add` to mark the file as resolved, and then `git commit` to complete the merge.

Comment: You are right, I didn't find the way but it was too easy, thanks a lot @Simon-pearson.